# Laravel validator Parent id

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 9 ,

I have in table client column : id , name , parent_id , created_at

the parent_id is from table client , I need to add validation on update function to not allow client to be parent for himself :
i am using this :

```
  'parent_id'      => 'nullable|different:id',
```

but this not working , even it is exist on laravel documentation .

Comment: `id` likely isn't coming from the form on the Front-end, as it a) for new, should be auto-generated in your database, or b) for existing, present on the Model instance you're modifying. As long as you selected/entered a `parent_id`, it _would_ be different than `null`. You could add a `hidden` input named `id` that contains the `id` of the model being updated (unsafe, since it could be modified before form submission), or you could "inject" it into the request (`request()->merge(['id' => $modelInstance->id])`, or similar)

Comment: 1- I'll make `id` and `parent_id` unique, 2- as Tim said you can inject the `id` into request so the different rule validation can work with you, 3- You can create a custom Rule to check if current model hasn't the same `id` as the `parent_id``

Comment: you can create a custom rule ensure current record does not have the id same as parent id for more info visit laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules